# How to increase the chance for PhD admission while I am working?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I graduated as ***MSc. of Software Engineering*** in 2017, and then I started my career in the industry as "**software tester**".

I am going to apply for the [Graduate School of Decision Sciences](https://www.daad.de/deutschland/studienangebote/international-programmes/en/detail/4424/#tab_overview) in 2 years. The graduates of computer science are qualified to apply for this program, but there are 2 main issues which I am concerned about:

1. I am not sure if my grades are good enough for admission (My average is almost C)
2. There will be a 4 years gap between my master and the PhD.

I am wondering, how can I increase my chance to get the PhD admission?

One solution could be to contact a professor on the university and work on a paper, but I am not sure if it works well, or even they answer my email.

My question is:

***How to increase the chance for a PhD admission while I am working?***